# Redirect only root index.php to root in .htaccess, not index.php from subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to make some SEO adjustments on a 10 years old code base so I have to proceed with caution.

The task is to do a 301 redirect of https://www.example.com/index.php to https://www.example.com.

The current rules are these:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Add a trailing slash to non-files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# General rules
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)-(.*)/(.*)-(.*)/$ product.php?category_permalink=$1&category_id=$2&product_permalink=$3&product_id=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^categories/(.*)-(.*)/page-(.*)/$ categories.php?permalink=$1&category_id=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^categories/(.*)-(.*)/$ categories.php?permalink=$1&category_id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^categories/$ categories.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I tried adding the following rules and it works fine, but it messes up https://www.example.com/admin/ too and the website admin can't login anymore because of that.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

So what I'm trying to figure out is: how can I do the redirect only for the `index.php` file in the root, not for other subdirectories?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
> RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

The `.*` subpattern matches any URL-path that precedes `index.php`, so you basically need to remove that.

However, since you don't appear to be using a front-controller pattern (ie. rewriting the request to `/index.php`) you don't need the preceding *condition*.

The following would suffice (placed immediately after the `RewriteBase` directive and before your existing rules - in order to minimise redirects):

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. Preferably test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

---

If you wish to make this rule generic and avoid hardcoding the hostname (like your other rules) then you can change it like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.%1/ [R=301,L]
```

The `%1` backreference contains the hostname, less the `www.` subdomain (if any), as captured in the preceding *condition*.

---

You can "simplify" the rule and omit the absolute URL (making it root-relative). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

However, this will result in two redirects if requesting the non-canonical hostname or protocol (ie. non-www or HTTP). Not that that should necessarily cause a serious issue, particularly if non-canonical requests are rare.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and detailed explanation. I tested it and it's working fine.